# How to compile a code with a table having varying number of columns?

Tags: performance-tuning, syntax, compile, table

Consider the following table:

```
tabb = Join[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10^4, 4}], 
   RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10^3, 10}], RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10^3, 6}], 
   RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10^2, 8}]];
```

I want to make a test action with it: iterate over all rows; for each row, go over pairs of its columns, check some condition for their elements, and if yes, break the cycle. This is my implementation:

```
compcode = Hold@Compile[{{tabb, _Real, 2}, {number, _Real}},
    Module[{acc, row, mark, func},
     acc = 0.;
     Do[
      mark = 0;
      Do[
       Do[
        func = \[Sqrt](tabb[[i]][[2 (j - 1)]]^2 + 
            0.5 tabb[[i]][[2 (j - 1) + 1]]^2 + 
            tabb[[i]][[2 (k - 1)]]^2 + tabb[[i]][[2 (k - 1) + 1]]^2);
        If[Boole[func > number] == 1, mark = 1; acc += 1; 
         Break[]], {k, j + 1, Length[tabb[[i]]]/2, 1}];
       If[mark == 1, Break[]];
       , {j, 1, Length[tabb[[i]]]/2 - 1}];
      , {i, 1, Length[tabb], 1}];
     acc
     ], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"] // 
  ReleaseHold
```

However, I get an obvious error:

```
compcode[tabb, 1]
```

> CompiledFunction::cfta: Argument
> {{0.956551,0.882991,0.546208,0.449567},{0.827807,0.108611,0.555594,0.865325},{0.454828,0.998108,0.862129,0.0564911},{0.216686,0.559491,0.818527,0.624721},<<4>>,{0.27142,0.724969,0.787701,0.93513},{0.160126,0.775366,0.117752,0.0601435},<<12090>>}
> at position 1 should be a rank 2 tensor of machine-size real numbers.

Could you please tell me how to avoid the mentioned error but still have the compiled code?

An obvious option would be just to split `tabb` into tables with a fixed number of columns, but in the real case, the number of such sub-tables would be too large to follow this approach efficiently.

**Edit**

It turns out the answer is as trivial as possible. Just do `PadRight[tabb, Automatic, -999.]`, where the last number represents some number which may be easily filtered off... The only problem is that for a very long longest row, splitting the table into tables with fixed row lengths and working with these sub-tables separately may be faster than working with one large padded table due to the size of the table.

Comment: The variable tabb is declared as an regular array. Since tabb consists of arrays of different dimensions, input its rows as three variables with consistent dimensions. For a general case as this one, Compile does not get you great gain in speed because the reservation of fixed variables space dependent on input table dimensions is as slow as its manipulation by individual positions.